# How to get numbers separately in a 2-D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

This is the question:

> (g) Given the following declaration :
>
> ```
> int [][]hours = new int[3][2];
> ```
>
> which stores the weekend (Fri & Sat) hours worked (assume no partial hours worked)  for each of three employees.
>
> Write a snippet of Java code to:
>
> 1. calculate and print the overall total hours worked by all the employees
> 2. the average hours worked by each employee.
>
> Assume the array has been populated with data.

And I'm completely lost this is all I could guess:

```
int [][] hours = new int[3][2];

for (int i = 0; i++; i < hours[0].length){
    int totalHours;
    for(int j = 0 j++; j < hours[1].length){
        totalHours = totalHours + hours[i][j];
        System.out.println("The total hours employee " + j + "worked is " + totalHours + ".");
    }
    totalHours = 0;
}
```

Comment: In your first `for` loop it should just be `i < hours.length` to get the number of rows in the array. `i < hours[0].length` gets the number of columns in the array.

Comment: "This is the question: ...". I'm having trouble finding any question in the post. This is also syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `for` loops are not correct. The for loop should  be written like this

```
for(init variable; condition; increment)
```

So your for loops should look like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < hours[0].length; i++)
```

As for your conditions, the way you traverse a 2d array with nested for loops, is the outer loop will go down the rows. Thus your first condition should go like this

```
i < hours.length
```

Then your inner loop is based on the current row, or the value of i in your outer loop. So your inner loop condition should be

```
j < hours[i].length
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is a homework problem, I will try to steer you onto the right track.
 
For starters you are not accessing the 2d array correctly.

Here is an example of how to access every element in a 2d array.

```
int [][] hours = new int[3][2];

for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) //correct way to initialize a for loop
{
    //do foo to the outer array;

    for(int j = 0; j < hours[i].length; j++)
    {
        //do foo to the inner arrays
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a past exam question. I was half dead from hours of study that's why it's a lot more messed up than I had hoped. I have a test today and my lecture likes to be vague about tests so I was trying to make sure I know how to do every past exam question.
Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the for loop. Below is the corrected code:

```
int[][] hours = new int[3][2];

for(int i=0; i<hours.length; i++){
    int totalHours = 0;
    for(int j =0; j< hours[i].length; j++){
        totalHours = totalHours + hours[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println("The total hours employee " + i + " worked is " + totalHours +".");
}
```